# Send sensor data from Nodmcu to labview

Tags: arduino, labview, nodemcu

I want to send sensor data(like DHT) from NODEMCU to LABVIEW.
Is there any library or sketch to do this ?
NODEMCU  is connected to network in station mode.
In labview, I have to use which library to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :
1. Try this library in Arduino IDE: ESP8266WiFi.h

> host is your PC like 192.168.1.11
>
> port : 550 (for example)

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid     = "xxxx";      // SSID
const char* password = "xxxx";      // Password
const char* host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";  // Server IP
const int   port = 550;            //  Server Port
const int   watchdog = 5000;        // Watchdog frequency

unsigned long previousMillis = millis(); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if ( currentMillis - previousMillis > watchdog ) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    WiFiClient client;

    if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
      Serial.println("connection failed");
      return;
    }

    String url = "/watchdog?command=watchdog&uptime=";
    url += String(millis());
    url += "&ip=";
    url += WiFi.localIP().toString();

    // Envoi la requete au serveur - This will send the request to the server
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    unsigned long timeout = millis();
    while (client.available() == 0) {
      if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
        Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
        client.stop();
        return;
      }
    }

    // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
    while(client.available()){
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
      Serial.print(line);
    }
  }
}
```

2. labview : you need 2 blocks to do this :

> TCP LISTEN
>
> TCP READ